# Is there a jQueryUI LessCss template out there?

Tags: css, jquery-ui, themes, less

We are making extensive use of LessCss and and jQueryUI in a current project and we've looked all over for the jQueryUI theme in Less format. Has any one come across this? And if so, can you point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes there is a template file for jqueryui + lesscss on sourceforge

http://jqueryuilesscss.sourceforge.net/

I will be adding LessCss functions and slimming down the vars as I explore this more. The aim is to also add non js reliant :hover for all inputs/buttons etc

Comment: If there is interest in this project I will complete the less functions - im a little tied up creating a suite of asp.net server controls that sit in the jQueryUI framework but if I get requests I will complete

Comment: Could you make a copy of the repo to github? I think you would get more visibility and perhaps pull requests :)

Comment: @Guillaume86 - I am going to revisit this I think (recode the sheets and package them up a lot better + examples and more defined mixins)... should be about a month before I can get the time off other projects unless I get a buzz rush at a weekend. Thanks for the feedback

Comment: @PaulSullivan, This question was the first Google result for `jqueryui theme less`... Are you maintaining this solution at some other code hosting site, or have you found another solution in the period since it was last updated?

Comment: @Emyr I am willing to put it up on github or some other host so community can maintain - I have no time to extend work done on it but happy to open it to world.

Answer (score 2):

Leafo of the PHP .less project just released a feature that is designed to generate a .less source from a css file.  Presumably you should be able to use this to do what you are looking for.

http://leafo.net/lessphp/

Go here and try the lessify stuff https://github.com/leafo/lessphp

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made jQuery widgets follow the compiled twbs theme (for example bootswatch). 
https://github.com/DC-development/jquery-ui-less